# Oracle Connection Manager - Oracle Linux 9

Tags: oracle, oracleclient

I have have managed to install cman - Oracle Connection Manager on

- Oracle Linux 7 (install oracle-database-preinstall-19c) Oracle Client OUI v19
- Oracle Linux 8 (install oracle-database-preinstall-21c) Oracle Client OUI v21.3

I would like to install cman v21.3 on Oracle Linux 9 but the OUI isn't happy.

```
[oracle@cman1 ~]$ /tmp/client/runInstaller -silent -noconfig -waitforcompletion -responseFile /tmp/cman.rsp
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 415 MB.   Actual 28406 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 4095 MB    Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2024-01-08_05-02-31PM. Please wait ...[WARNING] [INS-08101] Unexpected error while executing the action at state: 'clientSupportedOSCheck'
   CAUSE: No additional information available.
   ACTION: Contact Oracle Support Services or refer to the software manual.
   SUMMARY:
       - java.lang.NullPointerException
A log of this session is currently saved as: /tmp/OraInstall2024-01-08_05-02-31PM/installActions2024-01-08_05-02-31PM.log. Oracle recommends that if you want to keep this log, you should move it from the temporary location.
[oracle@cman1 ~]$
[oracle@cman1 ~]$
[oracle@cman1 ~]$ export CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OEL9.2
[oracle@cman1 ~]$ /tmp/client/runInstaller -silent -noconfig -waitforcompletion -responseFile /tmp/cman.rsp
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 415 MB.   Actual 28407 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 4093 MB    Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2024-01-08_05-03-10PM. Please wait ...[WARNING] [INS-13001] Oracle Database Client is not supported on this operating system. Installer will not perform prerequisite checks on the system.
   CAUSE: This operating system may not have been in the certified list at the time of the release of this software.
   ACTION: Refer to My Oracle Support portal for the latest certification information for this operating system. Proceed with the installation if the operating system has been certified after the release of this software.
The response file for this session can be found at:
 /opt/oracle/cman/product/cman1930/install/response/client_2024-01-08_05-03-10PM.rsp

You can find the log of this install session at:
 /tmp/OraInstall2024-01-08_05-03-10PM/installActions2024-01-08_05-03-10PM.log

[FATAL] Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile '/opt/oracle/cman/product/cman1930/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See '/opt/oracle/oraInventory/logs/installActions2024-01-08_05-03-10PM.log' for details.
The log of this install session can be found at:
 /opt/oracle/oraInventory/logs/installActions2024-01-08_05-03-10PM.log
[oracle@cman1 ~]$
[oracle@cman1 ~]$ cat /etc/system-release
Oracle Linux Server release 9.3
```

Here is my responseFile:

```
oracle.install.responseFileVersion=/oracle/install/rspfmt_clientinstall_response_schema_v21.0.0
ORACLE_HOSTNAME={{ ansible_hostname }}
UNIX_GROUP_NAME=oinstall
INVENTORY_LOCATION=/opt/oracle/oraInventory
SELECTED_LANGUAGES=en
oracle.install.client.installType=Custom
oracle.install.client.customComponents="oracle.sqlplus:21.0.0.0.0","oracle.network.client:21.0.0.0.0","oracle.network.cman:21.0.0.0.0"
```

I am doing a custom install where I extract the needed components. Will it be better to extract them from the Database OUI?

Any advice appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`export CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OEL9.2` are you sure OCM supports RHEL9?

CV_ASSUME_DISTID variable is used to "convince" installer you're on **older** OS version and to skip certain OS specific checks.

Also from the logfile it looks like the installer failed to link/create libclntsh.so shared library. Most likely some static libraries are missing on your server.

Maybe `libpthread.a`? Check other logfiles - output from `make`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue on Oracle's side for OL9/RHEL9 machines.

I'll quote an article - https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=389683264885112&id=2969734.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=z0gvtzbr9_145:

19c Client Installation on RHEL9 / OEL fails with error :"Exception String: Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile" (Doc ID 2969734.1)

APPLIES TO:
Oracle Database - Enterprise Edition - Version 19.3.0.0.0 and later
Information in this document applies to any platform.
SYMPTOMS
While installing 19c Oracle Database Client on RHEL 9 or OEL 9 , below mentioned errors will be seen in the relink log :

```
INFO:
/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/client_1/bin/genclntsh

INFO:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a

INFO:
genclntsh: Failed to link libclntshcore.so.19.1

INFO:
make: *** [/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/client_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk:56: client_sharedlib] Error 1

INFO: End output from spawned process.
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Exception thrown from action: make
Exception Name: MakefileException
Exception String: Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/client_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2023-08-17_11-59-11AM.log' for details.
Exception Severity: 1
```

**SOLUTION**

1. Download the Oracle 19c Client for Linux 64 bit
2. Unzip the software in the desired Oracle Home
3. Install the software and ignore the below mentioned relink error you receive:

```
$ export CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OL7

$ ./runInstaller

Exception String: Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/client_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'.
```

4. Download and Apply patch 35042068 (ignore the OPatch warnings)
5. Download and Apply patch 35681671 (OPatch should succeed)
6. Run:

`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/relink as_installed`

(There should not be any errors)

PS: Most of the fixes are included in 19.22, so better to have 19.22DBRU applied

Answer (score 0):

I created an service request at support.oracle.com.

They replied back that the Oracle Connection Manager isn't supported on Oracle Linux 9 nor the ZDM (Zero Downtime Migration) tool.
Hopefully this will change soon.